# Where can I find the safe combination?

Tags: gone-home

In Gone Home, where can I find the safe combination (to the safe in the basement)? Or does somebody have a hint to where I can find it? I've been looking for a good while now and after discovering a lot of things which I missed I still can't find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The combination is the most recent year you can find on the wall near the safe.

Answer (score 14):

Its also on a scrap of paper found  on the floor after opening the secret door into the guest room.

Comment: I think this is the better answer from a problem-solving point of view, though that it is that date does underline the importance of that date to the storyline.

Comment: Not to mention that it actually *tells* you the combination, rather than guessing from the related clues. (Two ways to the same place, I suppose.)